# Excel for Mac 2011 move column 2 in sheet 1 to column 1 in sheet 2

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2011

I would like to move column 2 into column 1 for each successive sheet, one sheet per week, automatically. Is that possible? I do it with this formula ='1st week'!D2 and manually changing '1st week' to '2nd week', each week, but was wondering if it's possible to be done automatically.
Thanks!

Comment: Give us an example where you show what you have and what exactly you want

Comment: Is there a way to attach a spreadsheet here to show what I mean? Thanks!

Comment: 2 ways: Upload a screenshot at imgur and paste/edit the link to your question. A higher rep user will convert the link to a normal screenshot later. (Or) Upload your file at ge.tt and again paste/edit the link